# Memory leak in singleton class in c++

Tags: c++, singleton

i have a singleton class. I am creating an object of it. Using it. Once it will go out of scope destructor will be called.

Again creating anew object,  since instanceFlag is false, it will again allocate new memory.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Singleton
{
private:
    static bool instanceFlag;
    static Singleton *single;
    Singleton()
    {
        //private constructor
    }
public:
    static Singleton* getInstance()
    {
        if(! instanceFlag)
        {
            single = new Singleton();
            instanceFlag = true;
            return single;
        }
        else
        {
            return single;
        }
    }
    void method()
    {
        cout << "Method of the singleton class" << endl;
    }
    ~Singleton()
    {
        instanceFlag = false;
    }
};

bool Singleton::instanceFlag = false;
Singleton* Singleton::single = NULL;



int main()
{
    Singleton *sc1,*sc2;
    {
        sc1 = Singleton::getInstance();
        sc1->method();
        delete sc1;
    }
    sc2 = Singleton::getInstance();
    sc2->method();

    return 0;
}
```

My doubt is what will happen to old memory? I think its a memory leak. If yes how to fix this issue in the given code?

Any comments will be helpful to understand the internals.

Comment: Question: You are taking a pointer to it, so how does it go out of scope? The pointer can go out of scope, but the object pointed to cannot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Singleton design pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern)

Comment: when we allocate memory dynamically, but some how lose the way to reach that memory, then it is called memory leak. And this is happening in the above case.

Comment: if we have delete then how this code will react?


int main()
{
    Singleton *sc1,*sc2;
   sc2 = Singleton::getInstance();   
    {
        sc1 = Singleton::getInstance();
        sc1->method();
        delete sc1;
    }
 
    sc2->method();

    return 0;
}

Comment: ^ I think there should be `delete` in the destructor insteade of in `main`

Answer (score 2):

Pointers are variables that contain an address of something in memory. Like any other variable, a pointer can go out of scope, but that has no bearing on the information it is pointing to. This is how leaks happen.

```
{
    char* p = new char[128];
}
```

When `p` goes out of scope, the *address* of the allocation goes away, but the *allocation* is untouched; it is still allocated and its contents unaffected any more than throwing away an envelope affects the house it was addressed to.

To solve that you would need something with ref counts, like `std::shared_ptr`/`std::weak_ptr` or a RAII container like `std::unique_ptr`, etc. Something that has a destructor to go out of scope with.

It's better to implement the Singleton pattern with references.

```
class Singleton {
    Singleton() {
        // constructor code...
    }
    static Singleton s_singleton;
public:
    static Singleton& GetSingleton() {
        return s_singleton;
    }
};
```

or

```
class Singleton {
    Singleton() = delete; // if you don't have a ctor, lets not have one at all.
public:
    static Singleton& GetSingleton() {
        static singleton;
        return singleton;
    }
};
```

Comment: I like this answer. I must say though, I prefer using `= delete;` instead of private constructor.

Comment: Oh - it's actually implemented, not deleted - just an empty body because I didn't have anything to put in it.

Comment: There - I did one variant in each example :)

Comment: unique_ptr is not ref counted.  You're thinking of shared_ptr/weak_ptr.

Comment: I like this answer because it is clear, to the point, and illustrates the problem in simple, clear to understand terms with code.

Answer (score 0):

I use valgrind which is easy to use, it is used to detect memory leak.
http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html

See headfirst c tutorial to detect memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

`sc1` and `sc2` are pointers, they are not `Singleton` objects. There is no call to `Singleton::~Singleton()` when they go out of scope.

Your problem lies elsewhere. When you delete `sc1`, you're not setting `Singleton::instanceFlag` to `false`. That means that `sc2->method()` dereferences a pointer to a deleted object.

You should make the destructor private instead and introduce a new member function for deleting the object. Also, you don't really need `Singleton::instanceFlag`. Simply check for `Singleton::single == NULL`. When deleting it, set it to NULL again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the way you have implemented singleton pattern is wrong,

```
if(! instanceFlag)
{
    single = new Singleton();
    instanceFlag = true;
    return single;
}
else
{
    return single;
}
```

the whole point of singleton pattern is not have multiple instance of the class, but just one. using a flag like above is not a good implementation, you are not setting flag to true and hence making new allocation of the singleton class, which indeed violated the rule of singleton pattern

You can use something like below

===========================================================

```
public:
    static Singleton* getInstance()
    {
        if(! single )//check if class is already instantiated once (allocation already 
          //done)
        {
            single = new Singleton();
            instanceFlag = true;
        }
            return single;
    }
```

OR you can also use non pointer

```
public:
    static Singleton& getInstance()
    {
        static Singleton single
        return single;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Singletons are not supposed to be deleted.

Your question is [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/125562).